# Suspect Question

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am created a new data.
I writing a query as

```
"select status from sysdatabases where name= 'db_name'"
```

I am receiving the following result.

"665526"

But, this result must be is "1077936153".

```
sp_configure 'allow updates',1

Reconfigure WITH OVERRIDE
```

After writing ;

```
update sysdatabases set status = 32768 where name='db_name'
```

it's not updating.What's the problem here?

thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Updating system tables isn't something to be done casually. (Not that `status` is updatable through that view anyway)

Comment: thanks for your answer.But,what exactly should I do?What information do you want?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on? Why are you trying to update this field anyway? Am I to take it from the title that you have a database in suspect mode? If so what happened to damage it?

Comment: What you are trying to do is equivalent to taking an gas gauge in a car that reads "empty" and writing "FULL" on it in magic marker: you fix the symptom but not the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Updating sysdatabases was a way of setting the database in emergency mode in SQL 6.5 and 7.0.
If you're running a newer version of the server, use sp_resetstatus and ALTER DATABASE SET EMERGENCY to achieve this. You can then investigate what caused the suspect state, and try to repair the database.

Comment: ALTER DATABASE will also allow you to set this to an emergency state.  I think the syntax will look something like this:  ALTER DATABASE [databasename] SET EMERGENCY